# What methods/techniques can be used to reduce the number of branches in compiled assembly code?

Tags: assembly, branch

I'm trying to minimize the number of branch instructions in my compiled assembly code for a particular architecture where branch instructions are very costly due to the way the processor pipelining is implemented.

I could try to implement self-modifying code to reduce the number of times a condition has to be tested in conditional branching, but are there any other things I can look at doing?

Comment: sounds like homework question to me.  Why don't you find out how the original ARM chip dealt with this problem?

Comment: That's a big subject and a non-specific question.

Comment: If you're calculating an expression, you may be able to rewrite the code calculating it in ways with fewer or no conditional branches by employing some bit tricks with AND, OR, XOR, -, \*, arithmetic shift right, etc. What are you doing?

Comment: I didnt see where it said this was an arm, if it were an arm then there are easy solutions to avoiding branches depending on the code.

Comment: I intended this to be a question on my specific programming problem, which isn't directly to do with homework. It's a practical, answerable question based on an actual problem faced, that I believe I describe sufficiently. It's also reasonably scoped. Therefore, I think this falls within the scope of the forum. Thanks Alexey Frunze - I'll give it a go.

Comment: @Froskoy I still disagree - there are many different techniques for avoiding branches, which ones are applicable depend on the *specific* piece of code you're trying to reduce the number of branches in.

Comment: You need to be more specific: post the code you want to optimise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ***shouldn't*** care too much about the number of branch instructions visible in compiled code. You ***should*** care about the number of times a branch instruction is executed on the CPU when you run the program.

Two easy ways to reduce the number of branches executed:

1. If your architecture supports predicated instructions, then small `if` blocks can be generated with predicated instructions instead of branches. You can possibly ask your compiler to do this for you. e.g. If your compiler is GCC, then compiling with `-O1, -O2, -O3 or -Os`, or using the `-fif-conversion2` flag should do this.
   *Remember that: Big `if` blocks aren't if-converted because predicated instructions pass through the CPU pipeline irrespective of whether or not the condition is true. And this wastes cycles.*
2. Unroll loops. A loop means a branch. If you unroll it, you can get away with executing fewer branches (although in compiled code, you *still* 'see' the same number of branch instructions, right?).
   *Remember though: This increases code size. Which can mean increased miss rate on the instruction cache.*

For example:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
     LOOP_BODY;
  }
```

If N is known to be even, then unrolling twice manually is as easy as:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
     LOOP_BODY;
     i++;
     LOOP_BODY;
  }
```

When this executes, the number of branches executed essentially halves.

Again, your compiler can probably automatically do this too. e.g. GCC unrolls some loops with `-funroll-loops`.

There are a few other tricks the compiler can do for you. e.g. If it's GCC, then you should probably [search this page for 'branch'](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful. Thanks for also giving the GCC tips, since that's the first stage in my compilation process.